# Root of an equation given by an infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the equation $$e^{-x} = x-1 $$.

We know that there is only one real root, $r$. How can it be shown that $$r= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}e^{-n}}{n!}$$

Answer (score 3):

We begin with the equation

$$e^{-x}=x-1 \tag 1$$

Now let $y=x-1$.  Then, we can write $(1)$ as

$$ye^y=e^{-1} \tag 2$$

Therefore, solution to $(2)$ in terms of [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is given by

$$y=W\left(\frac1e\right) \tag 3$$

whereupon solving for $x$ reveals

$$x=1+W\left(\frac1e\right)$$

Using the [Taylor Series for the Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}e^{-n}}{n!}}$$

where the series can be found using [Lagrange's Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).